# how to redirect to home page using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I have the following which is my home page:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("OVERVIEW", "List", "Items", null, new { @class = "navItem" })
```

I have a logo, which I want make it click able and once clicked direct me to home page(the one above),the following does not work,any suggestion?:

```
<div class="nav-primary">
    <a @{Response.Redirect("OVERVIEW"); } >   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/theLogo.png")" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
<div class="nav-primary">
    <a href="@Url.Action("OVERVIEW", "List")">   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/theLogo.png")" /></a>
</div>
```